# Error message type int is unexpected while I initialized the variables

Tags: c++

I am new in C++.
I searched for some similar questions on Web, 
Unfortunately, I have not found an answer to my question yet.
I used Visual Studio Code as my compiler,
and earlier I thought maybe something is outdated,
but I ran this code on an online-coding test editor,
it did not work either.
So I guess the issue may be the code.
I changed int to std::int but it was unrelated.

My code is as below,
and the error message "type int is unexpected" happened on line 15,
which referred to i2, i3 and i5.
I saw other people replaced "class solution" with "struct solution",
and that worked.
However, I hope to know why this generated error, and how I can make it work.

Thank you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define NOMINMAX
#define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

using namespace std;

class solution{
public: 
    int nthUglyNumber(int n){
        vector<int> res(1,1);
        int i2 = 0 , int i3 = 0 , int i5 = 0; //initialize to 0
        while (res.size() < n){
            int m2= res[i2]*2 , m3 = res[i3]*3, m5 = res[i5]*5;
            int mn = min(m2, min(m3, m5));
            if (mn == m2) ++i2; // check which one is the smallest, sort
            if (mn == m3) ++i3;
            if (mn == m5) ++i5;
            res.push_back(mn);
        }
        return res.back();
    }
};
```

Comment: Use `int i2 = 0, i3 = 0, i5 = 0;`.

Comment: On a side note, your `#define NOMINMAX` is in the wrong place, it needs to go above the `#include` statements. C++ has [`std::min()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and [`std::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) functions defined in the `<algorithm>` header, you shouldn't define your own macros for them.

Comment: Thanks I changed that to #include <algorithm> and exclude those defined stuff. I used int i2 =0, i3 =0, i5=0; in the beginning. That was not the issue though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
int i2 = 0 , i3 = 0 , i5 = 0; //initialize to 0
```

or this

```
int i2 = 0 ; int i3 = 0 ; int i5 = 0; //initialize to 0
```

Your version is half way between, but not legal.

Comment: I changed to the second one, but now my Visual Studio Code complied OK, but the online coding editor showed "use of undeclared identifier "Solution", did you mean "solution" while I did use "solution"...not sure what was going wrong